# I had written a simple cobol prog in ECLIPSE. But i am unable to compile,run that program

Tags: eclipse, compilation, cobol

I had written simple cobol program in eclipse. 
For the first time i am using eclipse for cobol programs.
i want to know the steps followed to compile and run that simple cobol program.

Comment: By default, Eclipse doesn't come with COBOL support. What Eclipse plugin did you used, and what COBOL compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Though I have never compiled Cobol programs on Eclipse there are somethings that is common in program compilation irrespective of the programming language used and the IDE used to program in. Every IDE needs some stuff to compile/build the program you created using it:

- Access to the compiler for the programming language ( the colon/semi-colon separated directory paths listed in $PATH environment variable is used to figure out the location of the compiler ). Try **echo $PATH** on Linux or **path** on Windows command shell and see whether the cobol compiler is accessible from your $PATH variable
- There could be a way to configure the compiler you use on a per project basis. Just look under Project->Properties from the menu bar and see if there is an option for configuring the compiler.
- Next is setting the build variables to help the IDE find the libraries to compile and execute the program. Even this could be configured from the Project->Properties dialog. In that dialog look for **Build Variables** or something similar and set the necessary paramaters. In case of COBOL that would be the path needed to find the **copy libraries** you use in your programs.

Hope this helps.